# A player with global hotkeys in Mavericks for back/forward

Tags: keyboard, audio, voice-dictation

I want to use Dictatation in order to dictate a text that I listen in a headset. I would like to be able to pause and go back/forward without switching between the windows of the text editor and of the player.

Using global keys for this would be a  way. I already have the button f8 for pausing, but what about back and forward?

Is there a player with such global keys?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Automator to create Services that control the playback of QuickTime Player, then assign keyboard shortcuts to the Services in System Preferences.

The Automator Service:
[image: Play/Pause]

Keyboard Shortcut in System Preferences:
[image: Keyboard Shortcut]